# Neural network performance optimization

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent, multilabel-classification

I am trying to classify medical report based on the symptoms mentioned in the report. Steps i am doing are

1) Extract symptoms from each medical report.

2) Create a Set of all the symptoms extracted from all medical reports, total terms so far are 3700.

3) Create a set of all diseases diagnosed and mentioned in these discharge summaries, total terms so far are 1500.

4) Now i iterate through all the medical reports and create one hot vector for each report and its diagnoses. I have 5000 documents.

For symptoms, i am getting a matrix of 5000 X 3700
where each row represent a single document and each column show a symptom. If symptom is present in the document, the value of the column is one, otherwise the value is zero is symptom is

[image]

For diagnosis, i am getting a matrix of 5000 X 1500

[image]

```
I am using a backward propagating neural network for training. The network has 3700 input neurons, 1 hidden layer and 1500 output neurons.
```

The code is been used from here http://jrmeyer.github.io/tutorial/2016/02/01/TensorFlow-Tutorial.html for creating the classifier.

The problem is that no matter how much i train it (so far i have tried with 25000 epochs), i am getting very bad results,

Output has maximum probability value (1) for 160+ labels while i was expecting for 5 labels.

Is there anything that i might be doing wrong, or what should i do to improve the results.

Updates : I have tried to test the network with minimum data (100 documents and 85000 epochs) as well.

The one issue that could be causing the problem is that from each document, there are maximum 15 - 20 terms extracted, so the one hot vector has twenty 1s and 3680 0s. Can someone suggest if this could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't enough details understand you problem and implementation
but a good starting point that will help you understand if you have a more technical issue (bug, network architecture, etc...) or a data issue is to create synthetic data that you know should fit your model (fake some diseases, each with a set of symptoms)

if the model doesn't give the desired results, it's likely a technical issue.
if it does, it's more likely to be a data problem:  maybe your data is too noisy, or the underlying model is more complicated, or you don't have enough data.

Comment: Thanks for your responce, actually i have tested with customized data of 1000 documents. Plus i have updated the question too.

Comment: I have used the code from this tutorial http://jrmeyer.github.io/tutorial/2016/02/01/TensorFlow-Tutorial.html the only chage is that i am using multiple labels instead of 2 labels.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few things you could try (though these don't guarantee to increase the performance):

1. Plot learning curves to decide optimal learning rate, l2 penalty etc.
2. Generate synthetic data
3. Increase the depth of your network