# Is there a way to generate a completely new text column for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-science, huggingface-transformers

I have a pandas dataframe that contains multiple features such as age, gender , many symptoms with the values 0 or 1 indicating if the patient has that particular symptom or not and the target being his final diagnosis. I want to add a new column being the patient describing his symptoms based on the other features i have. Fo eg, if the features fever and cough have the values 1 i need the description to be "I have been experiencing a fever and severe coughs". Is there a way to do this without having to do it manually ? Because I have over 50 000 rows in my dataset.
Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated ! Thank you !

I tried using transformers's gpt-2 but it keeps giving me an error so another way would be much appreciated.

Comment: How variable do the descriptions of the symptoms need to be? Are you thinking of using gpt-2 because you need natural and non-repetitive descriptions of the symptoms?

Comment: Creating a new column based on previous data in a data frame is trivial, so it might help to narrow the scope of your question to the particulars of generating the data you want.

Comment: Yes, i do need the descriptions to be natural and non-repetitive since i need to create a chatbot later on that will answer any patient's description of symptoms with an accurate diagnosis. Is there a way to use gpt -2 so that it gives me text instead of numerical values ?

Comment: Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43571202/21891079) similar to what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. You will however need to key in manually what features lead to what description.

```
def generate_symptom_description(row):
    symptoms = []
    if row['fever'] == 1:
        symptoms.append('fever')
    if row['cough'] == 1:
        symptoms.append('severe coughs')
    # Add more conditions for other symptoms here
    
    return "I have been experiencing " + ", ".join(symptoms) if symptoms else "No symptoms"

import pandas as pd

# Assuming your DataFrame is named 'df'
df['symptom_description'] = df.apply(generate_symptom_description, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! I will be trying it to see the results.